# Are there pure abstract classes in C++?

Tags: c++, class, interface, abstract

There is a homework question which asks what construct in C++ is similar to a Java interface. An interface in Java can be referred to as a pure abstract class, and I know that C++ has abstract classes, but **are pure abstract classes something that C++ officially has**?

Maybe from a C++ designer's viewpoint it doesn't, but technically it is possible to create an pure abstract class in C++ by making all methods abstract right?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253642/what-is-the-difference-between-abstract-class-and-pure-abstract-class-in-c) resource but I'm still confused after reading some of the answers...

Comment: C++ doesn't enforce any particular style of programming, you can do procedures, or OOP, or templates. It also *allows* you to create an interface with only pure virtual functions, but it doesn't force you to. You can also use multiple inheritance with non-pure base classes - your choice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo() {};
    virtual void bar() = 0;
}
```

`Foo` is a pure abstract class in C++ because it contains the method `bar()` which is a pure virtual method.

Comment: You should use virtual destructor as well

Comment: I don't know C++ very well, so one question here; are the constructor and destructor declarations really compulsory here, given that the class has no state? Doesn't C++ fill those by default? Since I do Java, the rules are of course different, but I'd like to know...

Comment: @fge In C++ the base constructor and destructor are called when the derived class's constructor destructor are called. Your code will probably compile and run without the constructor and destructor. But to avoid going to undefined territory you must have a virtual destructor at least. As was pointed out to me when I answered this question and forgot to declare the destructor virtual ;) See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/461224/1517864) about virtual destructors.

Comment: @fge C++ will make a simple constructor and destructor; however, we need to declare our own destructor for an interface because we need it to be pure virtual (note in this example it is not pure virtual, but it should be). The constructor declaration is unnecessary: this class can't ever be constructed, and interfaces often don't have members to construct. The simplest interface would thus be: `class Simple { virtual ~Simple() = 0 {} };`

Comment: Constructor declaration isn't necessary.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, it is if the 'abstract' class has state.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create an abstract class in c++

```
class A {

public:
    A() {};
    virtual ~A(){};
    virtual void temp() = 0;
};

int main () {
    A a; // compiler error
}
```

Comment: why the -1 ? can you plz explain?

Comment: not the down voter but a pure abstract class should have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Yes you do.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270917/why-should-i-declare-a-virtual-destructor-for-an-abstract-class-in-c

Comment: @NathanOliver i know that upcasting through an interface can cause memory leaks because the destructors of the derived class will not be called. This example was only meant to be simple. Anyway i will make an edit

Comment: @NathanOliver couldnt agree more !

Comment: Constructor declaration isn't necessary.

Comment: `A a// compiler error` - of course, `;` is missing.