How to suppress warning W7041 in BCC64?
In a Borland C++Builder non-modern 64bit codebase (bcc64) that I'm working on, a number of class definitions emit the following warning:

warning W7041: Interface 'XXX' does not derive from IUnknown. (Interfaces should derive from IUnknown)

This typically happens in VCL projects (Delphi-style). Minimal example:
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();

    virtual void interface_method() = 0;
    virtual void concrete();
};

class TMyForm : public TForm, public Base
{
__published:
private:
public:
    __fastcall TMyForm(TComponent* Owner);

    void interface_method(); // override
};

The unit compiles and links, but emits the above warning. So far I haven't experienced any runtime issues, so I assume it does not cause any trouble.
Main concern: Suppress the warning
Rather than interfere with the class hierarchy, I would like to suppress the warning.
I have tried:

Compiler options UI - warning is not featured there
#pragma diagnostic ignored "-Wall" (Clang)
#pragma warn disable (bcc32 only)

But the warning still appears. I suspect that this warning is probably a language extension specific to the Borland frameworks. Therefore, the standard compiler mechanisms might not work.
Delphi/VCL conventions
One piece of additional information related to this issue: If class Base does not have any pure virtual methods, compilation fails, as in the following, modified example:
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
};

class TMyForm : public TForm, public Base
{
__published:
private:
public:
    __fastcall TMyForm(TComponent* Owner);
};

This time, the compiler issues the following error:
[bcc64 Error] test.h(21): Delphi style classes have to be derived from Delphi style classes


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618027/are-there-pure-abstract-classes-in-c

I don't think this question is related to the issue of abstract classes in C++. The interface IUnknown is something that is outside of my scope, and is not something dictated by C++, but by some framework. My question is rather related to controlling the compiler's consoe output.

An interface that is not derived from COM's IUnknown is indistinguishable from a pure abstract class declaration.  Other than that warning.  Basic reason why the C++ language doesn't have an explicit way to declare an interface.

Okay, that makes sense. The warnings occur in class definitions with multiple inheritance. However, my project is not concerned with COM at all. Therefore I don't think that warning is relevant to me. Or is it? Or can I avoid that warning without implementing IUnknown?

@Hendrik "I don't think that warning is relevant to me" - well, that depends. If it wasn't, the compiler wouldn't be warning about it. Is your interfaced class purely C++ only, or is it mixed with Delphi-based classes? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the warning.

Of course you're right. This is likely to do with Delphi conventions. I have edited my question to provide a minimal example, along with a modified example that fails to compile entirely, with a clear error message. I would still prefer to simply suppress the warning or find a way to please the compiler without spending time to implement COM interfaces.

While I haven't found a solution that works without touching the class hierarchy, and couldn't silence the warning either, here is one solution that has minimal impact.
Background:
The article Inheritance and interfaces | C++ and Delphi Class Models covers the relevant Delphi/VCL and COM conventions for multiple (or interface) inheritance and describes possible strategies for implementing the IUnknown interface.
Applied to the minimal example, the solution would look like this:
class Base : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void abstract_method() = 0;
};

class TMyForm : public TForm, public Base
{
    INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN(TComponent);

__published:
private:
public:
    __fastcall TMyForm(TComponent* Owner) override;

    void abstract_method() override;
};

The macro INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN will take care of implementing IUnknown using methods present in TComponent.
If you need to inherit from Base in a class that is not derived from TComponent, you can derive that class can from TInterfacedObject instead:
class CustomClass : public TInterfacedObject, public Base
{
    INTFOBJECT_IMPL_IUNKNOWN(TInterfacedObject);

public:
    void abstract_method() override;
};

If you cannot change your custom class to inherit from TInterfacedObject or TComponent, the only choice left is to manually implement IUnknown. (See the above-mentioned article.)
