# Is "polymorphic base class" a part of C++ standard?

Tags: c++

For a bass class that has a virtual function usually call "a polymorphic base class". In this case `Car` class

```
class Car
{
 virtual void drive(){std::cout << "drive right";}
};

class EuropeCar: public Car
{
 void drive(){std::cout << "drive left";}
}
```

Is `polymorphic base class` a general slang such as `pure abstract class` or a part of C++ standard?

Comment: Ahem, it's only the UK that drives on the left. I feel insulted.

Comment: British and french both in Europe and we drive on different sides of the road. A note before you have an accident on holiday

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard mentions *polymorphic class* specifically, for example, in **10.3.1**:

> Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented
>   programming. A class that declares or inherits a virtual function is
>   called a *polymorphic class*.

It also talks about *abstract classes* and *pure virtual functions*, like in **10.4.2**:

> An *abstract class* is a class that can be used only as a base class of
>   some other class; no objects of an abstract class can be created
>   except as subobjects of a class derived from it. A class is abstract
>   if it has at least one *pure virtual function*.

There is no *specific* mention of a *pure abstract class* (or *pure virtual class*), only pure virtual functions.

N.B: This is based off the draft standard, n3376.

Answer (score 5):

The C++14 standard does define the term "polymorphic class" (10.3/1):

> A class that declares or
>   inherits a virtual function is called a *polymorphic class*.

But it doesn't use the term "polymorphic base class".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about "slang" but a pure abstract class in C++ has a definite meaning.

A pure abstract base class in C++ has **only** abstract member functions (meaning they are all declared `virtual <return_type> <func_name>() = 0`) and no data or concrete member functions .

A polymorphic base class here is a much looser term in comparison.

Comment: they are simply words to convey a well known idea concisely, if you said "I made a pure abstract base class" I automatically know that your class only has abstract member functions and no data or concrete data members

Comment: Have to disagree... an *"abstract base class"* is defined by the Standard as any sporting one or more pure virtual functions.  "pure" has no special formal meaning for classes, so seems a tautological reference to the same type of function.  That C++ Standard definition is no way excludes *"data or concrete member functions"* the way this answer suggests.

Comment: I was describing a "pure abstract base class" not an abstract base class

Comment: @shafeen: I know... as I said, describing classes as "pure" is not C++ Standard terminology, and will likely be dismissed by other C++ programmers as a tautological reference to the pure virtual function(s) an abstract class necessarily contains.

Comment: true, I wasn't claiming to cite C++ standard terminology, simply explaining what a commonly used term may mean from another fellow C++ programmer

Comment: I understand - just saying it's contentious - some programmers will use the term the way you suggest, and others will think you're making a poorly-phrased mention of abstract classes.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253642/what-is-the-difference-between-abstract-class-and-pure-abstract-class-in-c) for a question that shows how the term is not universally understood.