# Full abstraction in java without interfaces

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, abstraction

I know that we can achieve 100% abstraction in java with interfaces and partial abstraction with abstract classes.

In interview, interviewer asked me to tell any other way to achieve 100% abstraction except interfaces. Is there any other way?

Comment: Note (for the next interviewer) that with Java 8's default methods, interfaces do not guarantee 100% abstraction anymore. But you still _can_ use them to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One could use pure abstract classes with abstract methods only (no fields, no concrete methods).

**Edit**: Note that starting with the addition of default methods in Java 8, interfaces are no longer *necessarily* 100% abstract.

In the real world, abstract classes without fields (avoiding state distributed across the hierarchy) are probably more common than pure abstract classes.

Answer (score 7):

Use abstract classes that don't have implemented methods. These pure abstract classes like the interfaces has zero implementation.

If you want to learn about *pure* abstract classes and why they can be used instead of interfaces, you could read [pure abstract class and interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2091893/573032).

Answer (score 1):

You have already got your answer i guess as mentioned by Stefan. However, I would like to add that the intention behind creation of abstract classes is to protect the developer to write the same methods for different classes and increase re-usability.